# Problem with [poco] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I just happened across the [poco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poco) tag on a question and I was curious to know what it added to the question so I read the description. The description is:

> Means Plain Old CLR Object, a simple object that does not follow any
>   object model, convention or framework. Can also refer to the POCO C++
>   library (http://pocoproject.org) for building networked applications.

Two things strike me for this. Firstly that it seems initially to be a non-tag. ie a tag that says I'm not doing something rather than a positive tag saying I am using/doing something. This strikes me as not that helpful.

Worse still though is that as you read on it seems that this tag description says that it refers to two totally different things. Having had a quick glance at the questions it does indeed seem to be used for both meanings.

I wasn't sure what should be done about this but figured that it is a point which probably could and should be cleared up a bit so thought I would raise it here.

My instinct is that it should be used for the C++ library which is a thing and that it isn't useful to use it in the CLR sense. I may be wrong on that though...

Comment: See also: POJO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pojo It's the same kind of negative-meaning tag, but it least it only has *one* negative meaning. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I probably wouldn't have cared so much if not for the multiple definitions thing going on which is just a critical fail for a tag really. :(

Comment: I edited the WIKI entry because there is already an existing tag specific to POCO libraries, [poco-libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poco-libraries).  There probably needs to be a cleanup run through [poco].

Comment: Related clean-up request https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309864/cleanup-for-poco-poco-libraries

Comment: I don't think that description does the concept justice. To me it's not it's a negative saying what you're not doing, but rather it's a list of what you can do, with one less item than similar lists. e.g. An EF Model can use CLR Types, and parts of EF, and nothing else. A POCO Model can use CLR Types, and nothing else. They're useful for serialization because you're limited to primitive types, without pollution from opinionated frameworks/libraries. The overloading of the tag isn't good. Might I suggest one generic tag: Plain Old Object, or POO! (well, maybe not...)

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object) has a better description: "In software engineering, a plain old CLR object (POCO) is a simple object created in the Common Language Runtime (CLR) of the .NET Framework which is unencumbered by inheritance or attributes."