# Cleanup for [poco] / [poco-libraries]?

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

There seem to be quite a few questions on Stack Overflow that ask about [poco-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poco-libraries) and have the [poco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poco) (as in Plain Old CLR Object) tag instead. Re-tagging some of them automatically might be possible (by looking for `Poco::` or `#include "Poco` in the question body), but reading the question in question is still necessary in a lot of cases.

When I started doing just that, [JAL alerted me to the fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799995/c-regular-expressions?noredirect=1#comment55038656_5799995) that each one of my edits bumped the edited question back to the front page of Stack Overflow. So now I'll hold back a moment and ask if there is a more general solution to this problem.

My feeling is that roughly half the questions in the [poco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poco) tag are about the libraries, not Plain Old CLR Objects, and in fact I almost stumbled over the similarity myself when I was asking a [poco-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poco-libraries) question and just added the [poco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poco) tag at first.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you need to mass edit, in general you should post on meta about it (get community consensus, extra help), wait until you have 2k (edit privileges) so your edits don't flood the review queue, and rate-limit yourself (don't bump everything to the front page at once).

Comment: @approxiblue: thanks for the edit -- I was unaware of the `[tag:x] ` markup. :-)

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275970/problem-with-poco-tag